# Looking for a specific variant of Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: identify-this-game, quarto

I came across a nice variant of Tic-Tac-Toe game, but since I don't know the game, nor remember the exact parameters of the game, it is hard to find info about it, as existence of optimal strategies etc. The part where I'm not sure is the dimension of the grid, but I think it was 4x4 because of the nature of the pieces. Each pieces have four traits, 2 possibilities for each trait. For example, the traits of the game I saw were:

1: Height (Small or tall)

2: Color (White or black)

3: Shape (circle or square)

3: Fillness (Filled or with a hole)

Most likely all 16 possible pieces were present. Now here is how the game is played:

Player A has the white pieces, player B has the black one. On player's A turn, he gives one of his piece to player B and player B decides where he puts it. He then gives one of his (B's) piece to A and A places it where ever he may wants. This keep going on until a player places a piece that gives a Tic-Tac-Toe, a Tic-Tac-Toe being 4 aligned pieces that possess a same traits.

I hope I am making myself clear.

Comment: Thanks! I plan on making a course on games based around math and mathemagic trick. (not in in short time frame but eventually) So I'm trying to get some ideas of games that could be interesting

Comment: You may be interested in Connect4 or GoMoku too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quarto!](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/681/quarto) is the game you have in mind.

Comment: That's exactly it thanks. Do you know about strategies if they exist?

Comment: I do not, sorry. It has been a while since I have played the game.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien - ask for strategies as a separate question.  I've played some Quarto in my day.